# SQL CASE Statement in WHERE clause to search for existence of value in any row of column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
Event      StaffName                JobRole
Event 1    FirstName LastName1      Subordinate Type 1
Event 1    FirstName LastName2      Subordinate Type 2
Event 2    FirstName LastName3      Supervisor
Event 2    FirstName LastName4      Subordinate Type 1
Event 2    FirstName LastName5      Subordinate Type 2
```

My query feeds a larger report that generates one report per returned row, but only if certain criteria are met. I am trying to create a WHERE clause that does the following:

- If a Supervisor is working an Event, generate one report per
  supervisor only. Subordinates do not need reports.
- If there is no Supervisor assigned to an Event, generate one report per Subordinate Type 1 only. (Ideally it would be a single report no matter how many Subordinates were working that event, but I can live without this.)
- Subordinate Type 2 won't ever need a report

I tried the following based on some suggestions I saw elsewhere (the Event criteria is specified as part of running the report and so is not included in the query):

```
WHERE
JobRole LIKE 
(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT JobRole
                   FROM Table
                   WHERE JobRole LIKE 'Supervisor') 
      THEN 'Supervisor'
    ELSE 'Subordinate Type 1'
END)
```

This works fine when a Supervisor is assigned to an event (i.e. Event 2), but returns zero values when the Supervisor does not exist for a given event (i.e. Event 1). I'm not sure why the ELSE bit isn't kicking in, but admittedly I'm not overly familiar with the nuances of EXISTS.

I'm working in SQL Server Management Studio 2012, if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `like` if you are comparing without any wildcard. I would use `=` instead.

Comment: There will be a wildcard for my actual JobRoles, I've just simplified them here for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Although, it will perform poorly and won't handle to have only one report for subordinate type1, your code should work. I suspect your data isn't actually like you think it is or you have a typo. I would double check the value to see that they are really the same as what you wrote in your condition.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "your data isn't actually like you think it is"? There definitely isn't a typo, but it's possible I'm misunderstanding something about the data.

Comment: Please mark the answer that solved your problem as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE (JobRole = 'Supervisor') -- is supervisor
OR (JobRole = 'Subordinate Type 1'  -- or is Subordinate Type 1 and...
    and Event not in (select distinct event -- not is event with superv.
                      from Table 
                      where JobRole = 'Supervisor') 
   )
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score -1):

This is better done as an OR:

```
WHERE (JobRole = 'Supervisor' or JobRole = 'Subordinate Type 1')
```

Note that without wildcards in the text you're testing against, LIKE is equivalent to = and so to make clearer what's happening it's better (IMHO) to use =.

Comment: This will generate report for Subordinate of event #2

Comment: I'm pretty sure that functionally this is equivalent to the WHERE clause you've shown. Judging by your reply to the comment above I don't think you've explained the problem fully; for example your comment says wild cards will be required. Given your explanation in the question I don't see how they can be.

Comment: I don't say wildcard required, I said use `=` if there is no wild card and no it is not equivalent

Comment: Yep, this was one of my earliest attempts at solving this problem before I got more complicated using EXISTS; it solves the Event 2 issue, but creates a new one for Event 1 because it returns both Supervisor(s) and Subordinate(s) and not just the Supervisor.

Comment: @ Simon -- there are dozens of types of JobRoles in this particular table, so for example there might be several different kinds of supervisors. The wildcards will let me return any type of Supervisor role; the same is true for the subordinates, though in my example I reduced it to two so I could show how some subordinates might be correctly excluded.